# SQL query JOIN a table on itself (separate IDs and Titles tables)

Tags: sql, select, join

**Order table**

```
o_id   customer_id   drink_id   food_id
----   -----------   --------   -------
 1         22         10          12
 2         22         11          12
 3         22         11          12
 4         44         11          13
 5         22         11          13
```

**Title table**

```
t_id   title_id   type      title
----   --------   ----      -----
 1        10      drink     Black Velvet
 2        11      drink     Mojito
 3        12      food      Rice
 4        13      food      Meat
```

## How to produce this result:

Given for example **customer_id = 22**

```
o_id   drink_id   drink_title   food_id   food_title
----   --------   -----------   -------   ----------
 1        10     Black Velvet     12         Rice
 2        11        Mojito        12         Rice
 3        11        Mojito        12         Rice
 5        11        Mojito        13         Meat
```

I don't know if the right way to do this:

1. A nested `SELECT` query?
2. Or a `JOIN` on the order table on itself after a rename? ( if this is the case how should the query look like? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `join` the `title` table multiple times to the `orders` table:

```
select o.o_id, o.drink_id, t.title drink_title, o.food_id, t2.title food_title
from orders o 
    inner join title t on o.drink_id = t.type
    inner join title t2 on o.food_id = t2.type
where o.customer_Id = 22
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59d81/1)

Comment: Thanks for ur nice answer, but the I had a mistake in its body. please take a look at `type` field again, if possible.

Comment: @Arash -- Just change the joins to use `title_id` instead of `type`.  If the same `title_id` can be used for different types, then you'll want to add the `type` to the `join` as well.  If not, it's not needed.  Same concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function and get results :

```
SELECT o_id,
       drink_id,
       getOrderTitle(drink_id) AS drink_title,
       food_id,
       getOrderTitle(food_id) AS food_title
  FROM Order;
```

Create function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getOrderTitle (startValue IN NUMBER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   orderTitle VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   SELECT title
     INTO orderTitle
     FROM Title 
     WHERE title_id = startValue;
   RETURN orderTitle;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made some editing to my question and it is now revised. please take a look if possible

Comment: @Arash As per updated table definition, I have updated function.